# Print sequence alignment to file

Tags: r, alignment, sequence, bioconductor, sequence-alignment

I do a simple pairwise DNA sequence alignment with pairwiseAlignment from the Biostrings package in Bioconductor:

```
library('Biostrings')
seq1 = 'ATGCTA'
seq2 = 'ATGTA'
pairwiseAlignment(pattern = seq1, subject = seq2)
```

The output looks as follows:

```
Global PairwiseAlignedFixedSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: [1] ATGCTA 
subject: [1] ATG-TA 
score: -4.091219
```

For very long sequences, the output is truncated and only one line is shown:

```
Global PairwiseAlignedFixedSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: [1] AT-------------------------------------------------...----------------TGTCTTCCAKATCTGGCGCGCCTGGGTTGATATC 
subject: [1] ATTGGCGGCCGCGCCACCATGCCAGAGCCAGCGAAGTCTGCTCCCGCCCCG...GAAGGCTGTATGCTGTTGTCTTCAAGATCTGGTACCGCTGGGTTGATATC 
score: -29418.8
```

How can I output the complete alignment to a text file?

Comment: why not ask on the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) mailing list? No subscription required. I think the answer is 'you can't, directly', but something like `as.character(pattern())` will provide you with something useful.

Comment: just sent a mail to the list ...

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this?

Comment: It's in the making, check bioconductor mailing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the discussion on the bioconductor mailing list. So far there is no easy way to print the alignment formatted, but maybe it's worth implementing.

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2012-April/044904.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that the R function `printPairwiseAlignment()` from `Biostrings` package is designed to do this the way I imagine you're looking for.